# upload pics to Google+ and Pintrest without user intervention?

Tags: android, facebook, upload, google-plus, pinterest

I want to upload pics to G+ and Pintrest without user intervention in background without using INTENT or any kind of user interaction.

I have found the api's for Facebook and twitter. 
For G+ i found those API's to be read only. Are there any such available for G+ and Pintrest?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google+ already [supports uploads of photos for auto backup](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2910392) if enabled, for Pinterest you will have to check out their API documentation about uploading photo's. further more you might want to investigate if users truly want to upload there photo's with out user interaction.

BTW facebook also uploads all photo's taken on the device if this option is enabled, same Google+

Answer (score 0):

Check [Android Pin It SDK](http://developers.pinterest.com/android/) given by Pinterest.

Regarding G+, you won't be able upload anything from Android app because currently API is only READ ONLY. Yes you can integrate **[Share plugin](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/)** which would help user to share rich content from app into the Google+ stream, including links, photos and location.

Comment: I checked the demo they gave but it needs to have The PINTERST app to be installed in the device.
And my requires sign in before uploading. So if i sign in to FB and twitter using my app, it uploads via that account and not the one's the app is signed in with.